# IE6 can't handle SSRS grid?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, ssrs-2008

SQL Server 2008 DB, report server, and IIS all on same Win XP machine inside firewall.
(Dev machine--production will be on a Win Server 2003 or 2008)

Test data is February, 21.5K records.  Presumable other months will be similar.

Client and tester are Win XP SP3 with IE6.  Long story, but **can't** change from IE6.

Report Server log shows that fetching, filtering, and rendering are all done within a little over one second.

If the parameter settings are such that the result set is 3,117 records, Visual Studio renders in ten seconds, IE6 in about a minute.

For a larger result set (not sure exactly, probably around eight thou), Viual Studio renders in fifteen seconds OR crashes.  IE6 hangs forever.

Same parameters, Chrome thinks it's done in fifteen seconds.  Doesn't display grid, but export to Excel works.

Safari, Opera, Firefox all fail to do authentication pass-through.

Not yet able to try IE7/8/9/... due to requirement to have IE6 on development machine.  (Not that it matters, since client can't use it but I wanted to compare).

Unless a resolution can be found, I am going to have to give the client a pre-formatted URI for an Excel dump and have her do the filtering in Excel.

Comment: oh dear, people are *still* insisting on IE6 :-(  My opinion: Any time anyone insists on something working in IE6, double your quote for the development cost. And tell them it'll cost more again to update the site when they do finally want to upgrade their browser.

Comment: What version of the .Net framework are these machines running?

Comment: Unfortunately, WE are still insisting on IE6, because when we purchased a certain system back in ancient history, the general public had not learned that IE6 is crap.  And since this system affects the safety of hospital patients, we have to be very careful how we replace it.  But we ARE working on that.  Not that it matters, because I have since learned that IE7 and IE8 also crash.

Comment: Framework: I was using Visual Studio 2008, which I think means 3.5 on the server side.  Client side, doesn't matter, which is where the problem occurs in Javascript.

Comment: Last time I was in here, I wasn't allowed to post comments. This time I am not allowed to post answers. Probably because I'm still forced to use IE6.  The only answers I know are better than nothing: (1) If you don't need pass-through authentication, persuade the viewers to use FireFox. (2) If you do need authentication, or they won't use FireFox, keep all the data in SQL Server, & use Access or ASPX to make a viewer; (3) Rather than an "everything" view by default, make them enter filter parameters to see anything.  (Warn them asking too much will kill the browser.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no answer.  We're starting to free ourselves from IE6, but IE7 and IE8 have the same problem.  And we're kind of stuck with them because we use Sharepoint.

The report works on FireFox, but FireFox fails to pass authentication through to Sharepoint.

Opera and Safari retrieve all the data, but don't display it.  (When the busy curson goes away, the window is blank except the toolbar, but the "dump to Excel" icon works!)

So, the sort-of answer is 
"The way to display huge amounts of data with SSRS is sometimes to not use SSRS"

I was starting to put it in another tool when the client decided other things were more important.